# How to fix:- libmxnet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, shared-libraries, yocto, mxnet

I'm trying to install mxnet on Yocto (Rocko) for my 64-bit Armv8-A. 
I did `pip3 install mxnet` and it was successfully installed. It was installed in -

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

I copied `mxnet` and `mxnet-1.6.0.dist-info` to -

```
/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages
```

Then, i tried `import mxnet` and it gave me the below errors-

**ERROR:**

```
>>> import mxnet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/mxnet/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/mxnet/context.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .base import classproperty, with_metaclass, _MXClassPropertyMetaClass
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/mxnet/base.py", line 214, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/mxnet/base.py", line 205, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**I checked and there is `libmxnet.so` in my `/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/mxnet/` folder.**

How do i solve this issue?

Comment: Why did you copy from lib -> lib64? If import was installed it will work, or change the *mxnet* recipe to install on lib64 do not do it manually.

Comment: @CleitonBueno: I copied from lib -> lib64 because when i did import it'd only take packages which are installed in lb64. But pip installs those packages in lib. So, i had to copy. 

Also, I checked without copying in lib64. I went to site-packages in lib dir and gave 
```
python3
import mxnet
```
Here, I got the same error as shown in my question. Just that, lib64 was replaced with lib. But, same error.

Comment: I have the same error, but i didnt move anything

Answer (score 2):

`mxnet` on ARM must be built from source, as per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/19234#issuecomment-699571539).

Instructions on how to do this can be found [here](https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.8.0/get_started/build_from_source.html).